Increment face selection size using repeat node
I'm trying to increment / extrude a specific face but the sequence seems to be out of order.  I'm trying to go from smaller to larger but it's reversed.  I know I can change the X translation to (-2) but that's just a workaround (the original object is the one being translated not the newly created objects) and I'd like to do it "correctly".

It should go from smaller to larger like this  See image below

Blend file


I don't understand your question : chances are other people won't too.

@Lutzi I'm already working on the answer ;)

ok I added an image of what it should look like

You do not have to transform the original geometry in the Repeat Zone, but the extruded geometry. And each new extrusion needs to be further than the previous one.
So first of all plug the Transform Geometry node after the Extrude Mesh node. Then I pull out a value from the Repeat Zone input to which I add 1. This is a counter for the steps, the result goes into the Repeat Zone output for the next iteration (it's a pity the Repeat Zone has no iteration output as a built-in counter).
And the result will also be used to be multiplied with 2 (or whatever distance you want to transform the geometry) and plugged into the X input of a Combine XYZ node. This is plugged into the Translation of the Transform Geometry node.

